# How to set a line border around a Layer in Pebble C API?

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Is there a way to giver a Layer Object in Pebble C a black (Or any kind) line border?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't draw outside the layer frame, you should want to draw a border just inside it.

You could draw the layer and then draw a rectangle just inside it.

OR

You could have a layer, and another over it, but slightly smaller and appropriately coloured and reduced in size.

OR

You could place a bitmap with the border on the layer.

**Edit:** Since you asked for code, here is some...

You register a callback after initializing the layer itself with this: `layer_set_update_proc( layer, layer_update_proc );`

Your callback (which is a separate function) could look like this, with other added garnish:

```
static void layer_update_proc( Layer *layer, GContext *ctx ) {
 GRect rect_bounds = GRect( 10, 10, 40, 60 );
 graphics_draw_rect( ctx, rect_bounds );
}
```

Comment: How would I draw a rectangle inside the layer? Code example?

Comment: For that, you need to get the graphics context, which is available only in the callback function (it's mentioned in the SDK docs). See this page: https://developer.pebble.com/guides/graphics-and-animations/drawing-primitives-images-and-text/ Once again, GitHub is your friend. There are multiple examples of how to (correctly) implement the callback function. It's quiet simple, really.

Comment: Also, in case you do not, for any reason, want a callback, you could simply add another (differently coloured) layer on top of the current one.